# How to write a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I have some callback function, but this dont work
I dont understund why

```js
const loading = () => {
  const callFalse = () => {
    return false;
  }
  const callTrue = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callFalse()
    }, 5000)
    return true;
  }
  return callTrue();
}
console.log(loading())
```

Return only true.
How fix this?

Comment: A function call can have only one return value. Your `loading()` function returns what `callTrue()` returns.

Comment: If you want to use the result of `callFalse`, pass a callback to `loading` that you call once the setTimeout finishes

Comment: I truly don't understand what you are trying to do. can you please elaborate?

Comment: What would be the expected output?